# publishProgress in Void cannot be applied to Strings in Asyntask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-dialog

I'm developing app to load pdf files in pdfView. I'm using Aynctask for this. I want to show the progress status in progress dialog.

Now the problem I'm facing is when I change `AsyncTask<String, Void, InputStream>` to `AsyncTask<String, String, InputStream>` percentage progress works well but pdf file not getting loaded to pdfView.

If I leave `AsyncTask<String, Void, InputStream>` as it is, I'm getting Error cannot resolve publishProgress, java.lang.Void in AsyncTask cannot be applied to java.lang.Strings. If I remove publishProgress my code works well pdf file is loading to pdfView but there is no actual progress update in progress dialog.
How to fix it? Please help me, I'm stuck here from many days.

here is my code for

**PdfViewer.java**

```
class RetrievePdfStream extends AsyncTask<String, Void, InputStream> {
        @Override
        protected InputStream doInBackground(String... strings) {
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            int count;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(strings[0]);
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                int lenghtOfFile = urlConnection.getContentLength();
                if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                    inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                }
                byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                long total = 0;
                while ((count = inputStream.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    // publishing the progress....
                    // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                  publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                return null;
            }
            return inputStream;
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
            // setting progress percentage
            pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(InputStream inputStream) {
            pdf.fromStream(inputStream).load();
            pDialog.cancel();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `<String, Integer, InputStream>` and pass an `Integer` instead of a `String`:

```
publishProgress((int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile))
```

Comment: I tried this still not working

Comment: @abhilashkaveriappa Why not? If you replace the `Void` in the class extend with a `Integer`, then use `Integer` instead of `String` in `onProgressUpdate` method, the error is corrected.

Comment: sorted thank you @cmak there was problem with ip it was blocking url. now its working.